# Easier way to execute Javascript code that replaces URL on website

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My wordpress theme generates automated links for me which I am trying to change. Thus, for all links generated by it I want to replace them with another link that I created.

Sample link created by theme: https://mywebsite.com/product/product1/

Sample link created by me: https://mywebsite.com/p/product1/

The difference is that I just create a link where **product** becomes **p**

I was wondering if there is an easier way to implement my code such that it shortens all links from **product** to **p**. The code I have below works but requires me to specify for all products individually.

This is the Javascript code which I tried on my site and a sample of the HTML code.

**sample HTML code**

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/product/product1/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
```

**Javascript code**

```
window.onload = function() {
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/product/sweets/"]');
if (a) { a.setAttribute('href', 'https://mywebsite.com/p/sweets/')}
var b = document.querySelector('a[href="https://mywebsite.com/product/chocolate/"]');
if (b) { b.setAttribute('href', 'https://mywebsite.com/p/chocolate/')}
}
```

Comment: Might consider doing it with `.htaccess` server side also

Comment: @charlietfl can you please explain what you mean? I am new to this. Thank you.

Comment: Read up on how `htaccess` works on server and how to do url rewrites. Those same links can be made to automatically redirect to different url structure

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the advice, would go have a read.

Comment: Just beware that changes made to htaccess can easily break whole site so make sure to always back them up

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps you,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link').find('a').each(function() {

  $(this).attr("href", newUrl);

 }).remove();

});
```